Someone seems to be on a delete-post rampage apparently targeting old posts that survived but accumulated two delete votes
I was looking through the recently deleted posts and it appears that someone has been voting-to-delete posts recently that had previously accumulated just two "delete" votes.
In my opinion, these posts survived the site's review process. Often such posts start out being mediocre, but then the poster makes improvements to bring it up to snuff before the post accumulates three delete votes. Then the desire to delete goes away and the post survives.
I have observed that sometimes users will cast an early "delete" vote but then neglect to go back, re-review, and retract their vote after the post has been improved by the author.
If a post survives - even by the skin of its teeth - I don't think that it is appropriate for one of our members to hunt it down later and cast the third and final vote that causes it to be deleted.
By adding their third vote in this after-the-fact way, the user is intentionally manifesting a bandwagon effect.
What this user is doing is unilaterally changing our site's rules so that in effect posts will be deleted after accumulating two "delete" votes instead of the required three.
Call to Action
In my opinion, our moderators should attempt to identify and revert all of the serial deleting done by this user. However, it might be helpful to our mods if some of the site's other high-rep users reviewed the deleted posts (see links below) and cast undelete votes on posts that were incorrectly deleted.
The Rules
Here are links to the topic of when and when not to delete an answer:
When should I delete an answer?

An answer that is not an answer should be deleted (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question etc...).


Answers that are answers but are factually wrong or are actively bad (say promote SQL Injection) should get downvoted, but not deleted.

(emphasis added)
Why and how are some answers deleted?

Answer posts that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:

commentary on the question or other answers asking another, different question
"thanks!" or "me too!"-type responses
exact duplicates of other answers
barely more than a link to an external site (i.e. the actual answer is not included in the post)
not even a partial answer to the actual question


Links to Deleted Posts
Below is a non-exhaustive list of links to posts that I believe were recently serially deleted in a manner that is inconsistent with the site's rules. Note that I can only see back 30 days.
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/48931/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/55312/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/59982/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/60569/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/61220/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/65690/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/65911/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/66758/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/65731/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/65404/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
...and more recent deletions, which probably occurred because I'm taking a stand here against overzealous deleting.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65728/22203
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65006/22203
(If you have edit powers and wish to add links to additional good-yet-deleted posts to the above list, please go right ahead.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I have read through the question and answers and comments (and I will review those ten you linked) but folks seems to be using the voting tools correctly in this case.
Your statement "I have to assume that delete votes on posts that have been improved are either bandwagon delete votes, or users who are voting-to-delete when they should be down-voting instead." is an incorrect assumption.
It doesn't matter if a post has been improved if the voter thinks that in its current state it should be deleted. It doesn't matter that others may have voted to delete previously - that is irrelevant to how any member of the community may vote.
Regarding those posts you listed, I thought I'd go through the exercise:
I would have voted to delete 6 of the 10, and down voted 3.

48931 - I would delete as not an answer
53731 - Link Only, so not an answer
59970 - I would probably just vote down, but I agree with deletion as it adds nothing to the existing answer
58736 - link only post, so not an answer
25541 - not an answer, possibly a comment
65688 - I would have voted down, but with the un-evidenced assumptions in the post, I can see why folks voted to delete.
65907 - I would not have vtd'ed as I think the post was improved sufficiently
66743 - this one is back in the undelete queue so wait and see, but I would probably just have downvoted, as I think the answer has assumptions that are not evidenced. But I get the comment around it not answering the question
19418 - not an answer
65398 - not an answer


Good mod-ing Rory! I added my perspectives in answer as well. I hope that others will do the same.

Note that the Help Center page Why and how are some answers deleted? continues beyond the section you quoted:

Answers can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete any answer, and trusted community members can vote to delete answers that have a score of -1 or lower (3 votes will result in deletion).

There's no limitation there. It doesn't even point back to the above reasons. Trusted members of the community are just explicitly allowed to make their own choices on what should be on the site, both by the codified Help Center rules and the site's functionality. The trusted members of the community are also allowed to vote to undelete if they'd like to; there's a review queue explicitly for reviewing deletions. Feel free to cast your undelete votes!

By adding their third vote in this after-the-fact way, the user is intentionally manifesting a bandwagon effect.
What this user is doing is unilaterally changing our site's rules so that in effect posts will be deleted after accumulating two "delete" votes instead of the required three.

Emphasis mine.
No, the user is simply casting their vote, as they are explicitly allowed and empowered to do. The emphasized conclusion is patently nonsense, because the third vote is the one you're calling out. Three votes were required and three votes have been given. Two plus one is three.
I don't even think it's wrong to look for posts that have existing delete votes to then cast delete votes on; if someone agrees the post should be deleted, they have the vote to do so.  You actually have a -1 scored answer with two delete votes that I'm sorely tempted to cast the third delete vote on because it frame-challenges the question when there was already a direct, fact-supported answer to it. I'll let someone else do so if they choose.

Absolutely support this - any user with vote to delete privileges can use that vote as they please.

@RoryAlsop I think that is fundamentally at the core of the issue here. You think they should vote as they please. I think trusted users must adhere to these rules. Unfortunately, it only takes a small number of extreme-freedom-to-VTD-leaning individuals to wag the dog.

@phil1008 those rules aren't exclusive; they don't say that the only reason to delete an answer is those two, but those are occasions when the delete privilege SHOULD (affirmatively) be exercised. Trusted users are trusted to delete posts with negative scores, as is atop the linked page. If my judgment is that e.g. an answer is misleading to someone without relevant experience, I'll use the VTD I'm entrusted with. Just like EVERY OTHER COMMUNITY MODERATION ACTION, it takes other users concurring with that action for it to happen. That isn't wagging the dog. It's community moderation.

Not exactly an answer, but a reminder that we should take a moment regularly to check the review queue.
I think I've seen several sudden close votes on old posts for which I don't think there's any need to suddenly close. It's not like we're going to save disk space or decrease load times.
So when I see these, I vote to leave open and leave a comment voting to leave open because and add my reason, which is often that it certainly IS on topic, or that the question was clearly clear enough or non-opinion-based enough for the excellent and fact-based answers to have been posted.
So we all need to remember to click that review button to "help improve the site"


Note that this won't work for delete votes, because there is no proper review queue for delete votes.

For deleted posts, if you have access to the Tools, you can review them after the fact.

That user would be me. Sometimes, posts slip through the cracks of low quality posts review queue. I was not on a rampage deleting anything with 2 delete votes (in fact, a mod check would find that many posts with 2 delete votes I did not VTD, and that many of my VTDs were on posts with 1 or 0 VTDs). I was carefully checking through to see if those posts should be deleted, and in fact I would say that the vast majority of posts I checked I did not cast delete votes on (regardless of the number of previous delete votes).
If you have an issue with a specific post that I or anyone voted to delete, you can bring that up ina comment on the post, a flag, or a chat room. We all do make mistakes, if you think someone (or multiple someone’s) did, please let them know.
I only started doing this roughly a week ago, so those are all the posts, by the way.
I don’t think this is against the sites rules, but if it please let me know and I’ll stop.
P.S. I happen to notice someone has decided to mass VTUD these posts.

When a first delete vote is not retracted after the post has been improved, that's an example of something slipping through the cracks. I have to assume that delete votes on posts that have been improved are either bandwagon delete votes, or users who are voting-to-delete when they should be down-voting instead. All ten of the posts that I linked above should not have been deleted, in my interpretation of the stated when-to-delete criteria.

But why don't we start by asking you to take another look at my revised answer to your own question? Note that a low-rep user cannot see the deleted answers, so the question will look unanswered.

BTW, I did not downvote this answer because while I don't approve of what you did, I still think the answer is useful.

You’re revised answer to that question still fails to answer the question, even if it gets closer…@phil1008

But does it attempt to answer the question? I think you voted to delete here because you were not satisfied with the answer. I can accept that in your opinion it's not a satisfactory answer. However, "not being satisfied" and "not coming close enough to the correct value" are not valid reasons to vote to delete an answer. The answer might be of value to someone else even if it's not accurate enough for you.

@phil1008 when looking at your answer for some reason I was still looking at an earlier version. I do now think it attempts to answer the question, and I have VTUD it. Sorry.

Hey, Thanks Starship! Very happy to discover that this was an honest mistake!

@phil1008 on third thought, I actually think I was correct the first time…

Ahh, did you change your mind because you didn't like this comment?

@phil1008 no. I would advise you to see Erin Anne new Q&A about your post. I remember thinking that the answer had a very large margin of error when VTDing it the first time and well… 33km/hr to 233km/hr certainly is. Last time when I looked at it for the third time I seemed to miss that and the other problems with the answer.

Since I asked others to review the answers and comment, I though I should put myself through the same pain.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48931/22203 - Should not be deleted as it captures some excellent back-and-forth between RyanC and OrganicMarble on whether LVLH (Local-Vertical-Local-Horizontal) is well defined. A link to an official definition (for ISS) is included in the comments.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55312/22203 - Contains a link to a very interesting chart showing STS-46 Ascent data which I think might be useful to someone and thus should be preserved.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59982/22203 - The poster uses language that suggests subject-matter knowledge, and there are no comments disputing any of the statements that he made. It is a clear attempt to answer the question. The four downvotes will probably make people think twice before trusting the answer. But we don't delete answers because we think they might be wrong. We upvote, downvote, and add comments.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/60569/22203 - The link takes the user to a really interesting paper that appears to be useful and relevant to the question. Reviewers wanted more details in the post itself, which were not provided. I think the punishment for failing to capture more details in the post (as opposed to in the referenced material) should be downvotes, not deletion.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61220/22203 - In an ideal world, this should have been migrated to a comment, not deleted. But as I don't think that's an option available in the review queue, deletion was the best option available here.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65690/22203 - This post came under fire because it used a high-temperature value in an example calculation. An early comment stated, "...its harmful to credulous readers to confidently state they might get that hot without a shred of evidence. I'm voting to delete. –
Erin Anne". Ample evidence was subsequently provided to justify the choice of value. The post was updated to make it extra clear that this value was chosen as an example to illustrate the calculation. However, fundamentally this post was downvoted and deleted because the chosen example value for Starship's stainless steel hull re-entry temperature upset some people.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65911/22203 - This question was improved based on community feedback and ultimately earned 4 upvotes. The earlier delete votes should have been retracted after the improvements were made. The final delete vote was cast recently (presumably by Starship) and this vote was probably not based on a thorough review of the answer.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/66758/22203 - This answer attempts to estimate the terminal velocity of returning-empty Falcon 9 booster. The poster of the question (@Starship) commented "You still don’t answer the question that I asked. You come closer, but this is still not an answer." This suggests that Starship's vote to delete was cast because the post attempted to answer the question but did not come close enough to an arbitrary and unstated accuracy threshold. This is not a valid reason to delete an answer.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65731/22203 - This is a straight up mistake. The answer says...

Even assuming possibility to create macroscopic quantities of antimatter using its annihilation for spaceships propulsion creates a danger of strong irradiation as the main product of annihilations are energetic gammas which requires a heavy shielding for efficient protection of passengers.

And a comment says

This doesn't answer the question, which is about the dangers, not the difficulties.

Probably that last person to cast the delete vote did not actually read the post and based their decision solely on a early and out-of-date comment by a high-rep user. Earlier delete votes should either not have been cast in the first place or should have been retracted after revisions were made.
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65404/22203 - This answer offers a unique perspective on the question by considering the diplomatic implications. It addresses: "Why is this method not used in practice? In what ways is it limited...?" It is not only an acceptable answer, it's a good answer. It even received 4 upvotes.
Summary
So, after a considered review, I think all of the above answers add value to the site, and only one (the comment) should have been deleted. Deleting posts does far more damage than leaving them up. Deleting sends a clear but disparaging message to all users that the Stack Exchange Space Exploration community is too difficult to please.

If they add value to the site, why don't they have positive scores?  If they did, they wouldn't be candidates for deletion at all.  But more people downvote them than upvote them. The value judgment is made before the deletion judgment.

Will another meta post get generated if this answer gets deleted?

Although I didn't cast votes on most of the linked answers, I think my delete vote on 65404 was valid. When the answer appeared in the low-quality post queue, all I saw was a one-sentence response with no sources or supporting information, which clearly qualifies as a low-quality post that should be deleted.

Some thoughts: thinking "something may be useful to someone" is not a valid reason to keep from deletion. Link-only posts are deleted - that's a fundamental SE function. Migrating to comments is a band-aid, as comments all eventually get deleted. Assuming the motivation for others is never a good idea, as you seem to have got a few assumptions wrong here about motivations that I know of.

@RoryAlsop, yes, upon reflection, I agree that deleting the comment post was correct. It would be nice if there was a "migrate to comment" option in the review queue, but I don't think that SE thought to add that feature.
